# Efficient and elegant way to initialize vector

Tags: c++, c++14, move, initializer-list

Given the following C++14 code:

```
struct A { /* heavy class, copyable and movable */ };

// complex code to create an A
A f(int);
A g(int);
A h(int);

const std::vector<A> v = { f(1), g(2), h(3) };
```

I know the `A`'s in the initializer_list are *copied* into the vector, instead of being *moved* (there are a lot of questions in stackoverflow about this).

My question is: how can I *move* them into the vector?

I've only been able to do the ugly IIFE (that keeps `v` const) and just avoids initializer_list:

```
const std::vector<A> v = []()
{
    std::vector<A> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(3);
    tmp.push_back( f(1) );
    tmp.push_back( g(2) );
    tmp.push_back( h(3) );
    return tmp;
}();
```

Is it possible to make this elegant *and* efficient?

PD: `v` *has to* be a `std::vector<A>` for later use

Comment: Why do you have a heavy class that requires free functions to create?

Comment: @PasserBy: That's not unusual or strange. If lots of setup is required, you _want_ a factory function doing the work, not a constructor.

Comment: Isn't this a problem only because of your fixation of the use of an `initializer_list` and/or other 'elegance'? What's wrong with having the simple code of `reserve()` + (multiple) `push_back()` (or `emplace_back()`)? This may not fit into one expression, but it's clean and clear and not slower than anything else.

Comment: @Walter: Meh, I get it. It's a lot more expressive. Hardly the biggest problem in the world, but I would also like a fix for this. Unfortunately I don't think there's one that isn't just worse than the already-given workaround (and the two answers below IMO show that)

Comment: Frankly I think initializer_list's behaviour is ludicrous here. C++ seems to be increasingly designed around implementation constraints rather than what actually makes sense to the user. I understand that what we read on screen is not what the compiler is doing, but as a C++ _user_ it is blindingly obvious that this particular utterance of `{ f(1), g(2), h(3) }` will never be used again, so its items should be moveable-from. It's frustrating to be repeatedly told that's impossible because of the reusability of `std::initializer_list` or w/e, when actually we should not have to care about that.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I think work should be split up and delegated to subclasses, and that would result in not insane code in constructor.

Comment: On the note of `std::intializer_list` being reused, maybe `std::initializer_list&&` should be a thing? Or `std::initializer_list<T&&>`?

Comment: @PasserBy Sometimes the code in the factory function is not the responsibility of the class itself and doesn't belong in the constructor. It could be specific to this use-case.

Comment: @PasserBy: No, there is nothing wrong with a free factory function. Do not make a mess by overdoing OO. Subclasses or no, you're still proposing all the work be done _inside_ the class, during construction. That's ungood. Prepare your resources first then chuck them at a constructor. Compose your program instead of lumping all logic in one step.

Comment: @Boundary Cannot +1 enough. `initializer_list` is awful

Comment: About initializer_list: I prefer simple expressive code that is also efficient. Here I have to make the code more complicated to make it efficient. All I want to do is create a vector with 3 elements, each of them temporaries returned from functions. It shouldn't be that hard, right?

Comment: About function vs constructor: I need the complicated work to be done in a function, that has nothing to do with the responsibilities of the class. The constructor should just establish the class invariants, no more. Also, I have several of those factory functions, some not even written by the class author.

Comment: About moving from initializer_list: could this be solved by adding a variadic constructor to std::vector, to avoid the limitation of initializer_list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it counts as "elegant" but you could use an array (or `std::array`) which uses aggregate initialization that doesn't suffer from this problem and `move_iterator` to move the values into the `vector`.

```
std::array<A, 3> init = { f(1), g(2), h(3) };

std::vector<A> v{std::make_move_iterator(init.begin()), 
                 std::make_move_iterator(init.end())};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P9pZrLjxkkQNkmyM).

Comment: The risk here is that `init` is used after it has been moved from.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I assume the scope of `init` is kept as small possible. Just create a function that creates your `vector` and returns it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin If you were really worred, you could encapsulate it in a lambda: `auto v = []{ std::array<A, 3> init = { f(1), g(2), h(3) }; return std::vector<A>{std::make_move_iterator(init.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(init.end())};}();`

Comment: I like removing unnecessary risks and complexity. Lambda adds complexity here.

Comment: Yeah and that's really no better than the original workaround.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It is certainly going to be better if you have many more items in your vector.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: That's true.

Comment: Worth adding a note to this answer that `std::array`'s initialisation doesn't suffer from the same problem (because it's just aggregate init), for clarity (I forgot for a mo :P)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Done.

Comment: I think this solution is clearer than the variadic proposal from the other answer. From the performance perspective I'd say both are equivalent, right?

Comment: @dats: I'd guess so

Answer (score 2):

You ask a C++14 solution, so you can use variadic lambda function with `auto` arguments.

Following the example of your lambda function...

```
#include <vector>

struct A
 { };

A f (int) { return {}; } 
A g (int) { return {}; } 
A h (int) { return {}; } 


int main ()
 {
   static const auto getVA = [](auto && ... args)
    {
      using unused = int[];

      std::vector<A> ret;

      ret.reserve(sizeof...(args));

      (void)unused { 0,
            (ret.emplace_back(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), 0)... };

      return ret;
    };

   auto va = getVA(f(1), g(2), h(3));
 }
```

If you prefer old type (not-lambda) function, or you want a solution that works also with C++11, `getVA` can be written as follows

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::vector<A> const getVA (Args&& ... args)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   std::vector<A> ret;

   ret.reserve(sizeof...(args));

   (void)unused { 0, (ret.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! IMHO, the (void)unused+comma operator+zero is a bit tricky for everyday use, specially for something that should be easy. One question: why is the std::move() necessary when calling getVA?

Comment: `std::forward<A>` is nonsensical in both code snippets, since `A` is a concrete type. It should be `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)` and `std::forward<Args>(args)`, respectively (and `args` needs to be made a forwarding reference in the latter).

Comment: @ildjarn - yes, I see the problem; on the other hand, the functions are returning a `std::vector<A>`, so (it seems to me) make sense a forward to `A`; maybe I could receive `auto arg0, auto ... args` and define `ret` as `std::vector<decltype(arg0)>` (make sense for you?) but (seems to me that) is inelegant and nobody guarantee that the types of the following arguments are compatible with the type of the first one.

Comment: @dats - yes: my solution is a little tricky; the solution from Chris Drew is simpler and more elegant (I think) for this problem but I suggest you to understand how work this solution because it's useful with a lot of problem based on variadic arguments (but starting from C++17 is a lot simpler working with variadic arguments). Anyway: the `std::move()` is an error from mine: as pointed by Barry, the value returned by `f()`, `g()` and `h()` are already rvalues. So `std::move()` is highly superflous (and I've removed it).

Comment: @max66 : The only _forwarding_ that can possibly occur is from _forwarding references_, using the same type as said forwarding reference (forwarding relies on/works because of reference collapsing). The idea is to pass each `Args` as an rvalue or lvalue of the _source_ type properly (_not_ the destination type), regardless of whether the argument type is an `A` or not, so that the correct `A` ctor will be invoked, regardless of whether that's a copy ctor, move ctor, or (most importantly for my point) _implicit conversion_ ctor (`emplace_back` should be used here, not `push_back`).

Comment: @max66 : (... continued) If someone passes an argument that is not/cannot construct an `A`, it will cause a compiler error; if you want a nicer error then the correct solution is to use a static_assert or SFINAE out the function altogether. TL;DR: as it stands, `std::forward<A>` is unequivocally incorrect. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn - clear and irreproachable; modified my answer according it; thanks.